# Extract value from multidimensional array and place in comma separated string

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array that looks like this

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Zeze
            [city] => Denver, 
            [state] => Colorado, 
            [country] => United States
            [user_id] => 1
            [cars] => Array
                (
                    [140] => Array
                        (
                            [cars_name] => BMW
                        )

                    [162] => Array
                        (
                            [cars_name] => Mazda
                        )
                )
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => Lex
            [city] => Schwelm, 
            [state] => North Rhine-Westphalia, 
            [country] => Germany
            [user_id] => 5
            [cars] => Array
                (
                    [140] => Array
                        (
                            [cars_name] => Mercedes
                        )

                    [162] => Array
                        (
                            [cars_name] => Audi
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I need to extract the value from `user_id` and put it in a comma separated string.

For the above array, I would like to get:

`1,5`

I'm a bit confused how to loop this array with `foreach` and then how would I create the string? Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$uids = Array();
foreach($users as $u) $uids[] = $u['user_id'];
$list = implode(",",$uids);
```

This is assuming your array is named `$users` and `$list` is the output.

Comment: This answer spares you the function definition and the callback operation. Additionally it might be easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
function get_uid($el) {
    return $el["user_id"];
}

$csv = implode(array_map("get_uid", $your_array), ',');
echo $csv;
```

Comment: Was just typing this answer and got the orange bar "A new answer has been posted".

Comment: thx - do you know if this solution is more/less intensive than @kolink's below?

Comment: This solution calls get_uid once for every item in the array. On that score it rates the same as Alec Ananian's solution.

Comment: thx jacob - sounds good, was asking b/c I'll use this to create a string with a user's friends which can get pretty long and require multiple runs of the function/implode/array_map (versus multiple foreach traversing the array + implode)

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over each item in the multimensional array with a foreach loop, and treat the item as a normal array.  Then push the user_id value into another array and implode it with a comma to make it comma separated.

```
$user_ids = array();

foreach($arr in $multidim_arr) {
    array_push($user_ids, $arr["user_id"]);
}

$user_ids = implode(",", $user_ids);
```

Comment: `array_push` is advised against when pushing a single value in favour of `[]`, and `implode` has the seperator as the first argument (they can go in either order for historical reasons, but seperator-first is preferred)

Answer (score 0):

This will be the most easier method:

echo implode(",", array_column($myArray, "user_id"));

Answer (score -1):

```
$stateId = Array (
     [0] => Array
         (
             [id] => 9
             [state_id] => 81
             [rto_id] => 82
             [is_active] => 1
         )
     [1] => Array
         (
             [id] => 10
             [state_id] => 82
             [rto_id] => 83
             [is_active] => 1
         )

 );

 $stateIds = implode(",", array_column($stateId, "state_id"));

 echo $stateIds;
```