# How to print a multidimensional (2d) array in separate lines with commas in between?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, data-structures

I have a 2d array that looks like this :

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [ProfileID] => SomeID
        [Practice_Name] => Test Practice
        [Telephone] => SomeNum
        [Email] => SomeEmail
        [Contact_Name] => SomeContact
        [Address] => 
        [City] => 
        [State] => 
        [ZipCode] => 
        [Verification_Status] => 
        [Last_Accessed] => 
    )
```

So I would like to print each array as "SomeID, Test Practice, SomeNum....." and then on the next line print the next array values.

I looked into this question - [Extract value from multidimensional array and place in comma separated string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479658/extract-value-from-multidimensional-array-and-place-in-comma-separated-string). But i was wondering if there is a way to do it without having to explicitly pass the field name for each like ProfileID, Practice Name, etc.

Comment: Check out the `foreach` and [`implode`](http://php.net/implode).

Comment: `foreach($rowSet as $row) echo implode(",", (array)$row);`

Comment: That isn't an array... that is an object ... you can make it into an array by an explicit cast   `$array = (array)$object;`

Comment: I think you want this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372127/phps-function-to-list-all-objectss-attributes

Answer (score 1):

As you have an object and not an array, so you need to hard convert it using `(array)`, example:

```
foreach($rowSet as $row) {
    echo implode(",", (array) $row) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Problem is that this method if theres a comma in a field value like in an address or a city, it separates those as well.

Comment: So, you'll need to use something like JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$string = "";
foreach($array as $piece){
if($string != ""){$string .= ",";}
$string .= $piece;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is untested:

### PHP

```
<?php
$array_keys = "";
$array_values = "";

foreach($array as $element):
    $array_keys.= array_keys($element).', ';
    $array_values.= $array[$element]
endforeach;

?>
```

Comment: Problem is that this method if theres a comma in a field value like in an address or a city, it separates those as well

Comment: @raeq You are right. Luckily it's not the only one available!